# Axios request error 404: can't find target file

Tags: reactjs, axios

The `nvm create-react-app website-react` command has been done and created the folder 'website-react'. I want to send a request to the file 'website-react/src/carousel-pics/carousel.php'. The .php file looks inside the folder where he's located to make a list of all images inside (this 'sibling files'). I've already tried so many different paths for the .php file. The component below is located in 'website-react/src/'. I know there are many posts about this error 404 in axios requests, but I've already tried (probably almost) everything. I'm starting to think "It's a React bug/issue."
`

```
class Carousel extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pics : [],
            ind : 0
        };
    }
    componentDidMount () {
        this.ajax();
    }
    ajax() {
        console.log("begin of ajax");
        const axios = require('axios');
        var data1 = new FormData();
        data1.set('op', "1");
        axios({
            url : "/website-react/src/carousel-pics/carousel.php",
            method : "POST",
            data : data1
        }).then(response =>{
                alert(JSON.stringify(response.data));
                this.setState({pics : response.data});
            });
        console.log("end of ajax");
    }
    render () {
        var num = this.state.pics.length;
        if (num == 0) {
            return <div>no pics</div>;
        }
        return (<img src = {this.state.pics[this.state.ind]} />);
    }
}
```

`

Comment: your php script should be in a separate project, running via an http server like apache or nginx.

Comment: Ok, no error 404, but now I get cross-origin issue.

Comment: Put it in the very top of php file
`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`

Comment: Thanks, everyone! It's working just fine now.